# How to know which values of $x$ can be used to find the unknowns $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm having trouble understanding what my maths textbook says, and I've not been able to find help. I would appreciate an explanation in simple (high-school) terms.

---

#### Worked example

**Question**

> Given that $5x^2 - 7x + 3 = A(x - 1)(x - 2) + B(x - 1) + C$ for all values of $x$, find the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

**Answer**

> Since $5x^2 - 7x + 3 = A(x - 1)(x - 2) + B(x - 1) + C$ for **all** values of $x$, we can select any value of $x$ to find the unknowns $A$, $B$ and $C$.
>
> Let $x$ = $1$, then $5(1)^2 - 7(1) + 3 = A(1 - 1)(1 - 2) + B(1 - 1) + C$,
>
> i.e. $C = 1$.
>
> Let $x$ = $2$, then $5(2)^2 - 7(2) + 3 = A(2 - 1)(2 - 2) + B(2 - 1) + C$,
>
> i.e. $B = 8$.
>
> Let $x$ = $0$, then $5(0)^2 - 7(0) + 3 = A(0 - 1)(0 - 2) + B(0 - 1) + C$,
>
> i.e. $A = 5$.
>
> $\therefore$ The values of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $5$, $8$ and $1$ respectively.

---

#### Question

> 1. Why where the values $x = 0, 1, 2$ chosen?
> 2. Can we use other numbers such as $x = -3, 5$ and $7$ to find the unknowns?

---

I'm not sure about the answers to the two questions above.

For **1**, I think the answer is that since any value of $x$ could be chosen, these were 3 random values.

I think that the answer to question **2** is also yes, but I was unable to find the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$ when $x = -3, 5$ and $7$.

Please could someone tell me if I'm right, or if not, where my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: It is true that any three distinct values of $x$ would be enough to find the unknowns. However, it is certainly not the case that $0,1,2$ were "random" choices. For instance, the fact that we used $x = 1$ meant that we were able to find $C$ without solving a system of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **1**, the values $1$ and $2$ are chosen such that $(x-1)=0$ and $(x-2)=0$ respectively. This simplifies the calculations. $x=0$ simplifies the polynomial on the left hand side.

For **2**, you can with $-3,5, 7$, but you need to solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}
69=20A-4B+C\\
93=12A+4B+C\\
199=30A+6B+C
\end{cases}$$

which is harder to solve than

$$\begin{cases}
3=2A-B+C\\
1=C\\
9=B+C
\end{cases}$$

obtained by using the textbook's choice $0,1,2$.

---

EDIT: To solve the first system, we subtract the first and second equations from the third, obtaining the equations:

$$\begin{cases}
130=10A+10B\\
106=18A+2B
\end{cases}$$

Now with only two unknowns, it is easy to show that $A=5$, $B=8$.

Finally substitute the values back to any equation and we will have $C=1$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to solve the first system though? I thought only an equation in 1 variable or a pair of simultaneous equations is solvable, and the second system seems to be a simultaneous pair already, with the middle equation being simply $C = 1$

Comment: *Usually*, a system of $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns can be solved with a unique solution. As $n$ increases things get messier. So it can be solved, using elimination and such.